# AppleScript: execute script on selected folder

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to modify an AppleScript "Copy folder tree" (by Jeff Fischer jeff@5fischers.org). This handy script lets you duplicate a folder structure but without the folder contents (i.e., the resulting copy of the folder structure has all folders empty).

Currently, the script works by prompting you to navigate to the source folder who's structure you wish to copy.

WHAT I WANT:
Instead of being prompted to navigate to the source folder, I'd like to be able to tell the script which is the source folder by **right-clicking** on it. Essentially foregoing the tedious navigation to it.

How can I modify this script to do this?

Here's the code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Copy folder tree
-- by Jeff Fischer <jeff@5fischers.org>
--
-- credit to Dan Decker and Robert Metzker for ideas from their scripts
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- make gFileTypes an empty set to omit copying/moving any files
property gFileTypes : {"psd", "jpg", "gif", "jpeg"}

tell application "Finder"
    set tSourceFolder to choose folder with prompt "Choose a folder structure to duplicate"
    if tSourceFolder is false then return "User Cancelled"
    set tDestFolder to choose folder with prompt "Choose the location for the duplicate structure"
    if tDestFolder is false then return "User Cancelled"
    
    my copyItems(tSourceFolder, tDestFolder)
end tell

on copyItems(pSourceFolder, pDestFolder)
    tell application "Finder"
        set tSourceFolderName to name of pSourceFolder as string
        make new folder at pDestFolder with properties {name:tSourceFolderName}
        set tNewDestFolder to (folder tSourceFolderName of folder pDestFolder) as alias
        
        -- copy or move over files of the specified type(s)
        set tSelectedFiles to (every file of folder pSourceFolder whose name extension is in gFileTypes)
        if tSelectedFiles ≠ {} then
            select (every file of folder pSourceFolder whose name extension is in gFileTypes)
            try
                -- uncomment the action you want, either copy or move
                -- copy the selection to folder tNewDestFolder
                move the selection to folder tNewDestFolder
                close window (name of folder pSourceFolder as string)
            end try
        end if
        
        -- copy over the folders, calling this handler recursively
        set tFolders to (every folder of pSourceFolder)
        repeat with tThisFolder in tFolders
            my copyItems(tThisFolder as alias, tNewDestFolder as alias)
        end repeat
    end tell
end copyItems
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to run the script by right-clicking on a folder you have to create an Automator Quick Action.

- Launch Automator and select New Quick Action
- Select *In the Workflow receives current **folders** in **Finder***
- Add a Run AppleScript action from the left side
- Replace the code in the Run AppleScript action with

  ```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Copy folder tree
    -- by Jeff Fischer <jeff@5fischers.org>
    --
    -- credit to Dan Decker and Robert Metzker for ideas from their scripts
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    -- make gFileTypes an empty set to omit copying/moving any files
    property gFileTypes : {"psd", "jpg", "gif", "jpeg"}

    on run {input, parameters}
        tell application "Finder"
            set tSourceFolder to item 1 of input
            set tDestFolder to choose folder with prompt "Choose the location for the duplicate structure"
            if tDestFolder is false then return "User Cancelled"

            my copyItems(tSourceFolder, tDestFolder)
        end tell
        return input
    end run

    on copyItems(pSourceFolder, pDestFolder)
        tell application "Finder"
            set tSourceFolderName to name of pSourceFolder as string
            make new folder at pDestFolder with properties {name:tSourceFolderName}
            set tNewDestFolder to (folder tSourceFolderName of folder pDestFolder) as alias

            -- copy or move over files of the specified type(s)
            set tSelectedFiles to (every file of folder pSourceFolder whose name extension is in gFileTypes)
            if tSelectedFiles ≠ {} then
                select (every file of folder pSourceFolder whose name extension is in gFileTypes)
                try
                    -- uncomment the action you want, either copy or move
                    -- copy the selection to folder tNewDestFolder
                    move the selection to folder tNewDestFolder
                    close window (name of folder pSourceFolder as string)
                end try
            end if

            -- copy over the folders, calling this handler recursively
            set tFolders to (every folder of pSourceFolder)
            repeat with tThisFolder in tFolders
                my copyItems(tThisFolder as alias, tNewDestFolder as alias)
            end repeat
        end tell
    end copyItems
  ```
- Save the Quick Action
- The action is available in the `Services` submenu of the contextual menu

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, I don't understand the step: 

Replace the on run handler in the Run AppleScript action with the entire modified script

Comment: In Script Editor replace the code as suggested then copy (⌘C) the entire code and paste it (⌘V) in the code section of the Run Applescript action in Automator replacing the sample on run handler.

Comment: Thank you again but I still didn't understand. In any case, I think I'll have to give up. Cheers!

Comment: Perfect. Everything is clear and now works. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to modify this script so that it prompts me for a new name for the top level folder?

Why do I need this? Because sometimes I need to duplicate a folder tree in the same directory. As it stands now if I try to save it to the same directory it throws an error.

TIA!

Comment: What does *top level folder* mean?

Comment: Top-level means the top-most folder (i.e., the folder being duplicated and which contains all other subfolders—which are also empty)

Comment: Replace `set tSourceFolder to item 1 of input` with `set tSourceFolder to choose folder with prompt "Choose the source folder"`

Comment: Didn't work : /     

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/58cz00z12s2wxwptlxdlt/Copy-Folder-tree-not-working-for-Stack-Overflow.mp4?rlkey=omevm32ibypw3j16wcpop2y4i&dl=0

Comment: It doesn't work because you choose the same folder for source and destination.

Comment: Yes sir. That's exactly what I was hoping was possible to do. As I mentioned earlier:

 "Is it possible to modify this script so that it prompts me for a new name for the top level folder? Why do I need this? Because sometimes I need to duplicate a folder tree in the same directory. As it stands now if I try to save it to the same directory it throws an error."

Thank you

Comment: Two items with the same name on the same level are not allowed. You could – like the Finder – append `copy` to the file name of the destination folder if the names are equal..

Comment: Yes, I know that two files cannot have the same name within the same directory.  Is there a way to modify the script so the dialog box that appears is the one that allows you to enter a new name?  Right now that's not happening.

Comment: Of course there is a way but this requires considerable changes in the script which is beyond the scope of this question. Please ask a new one.